MQL4 (MT4): indicator loads but does not displlay
In MT4 (MetaTrader 4) I wish to display the DXY indicator in the sub window of the chart automatically if the currency pair on the chart has USD in it (EURUSD, USDCAD, USDJPY, etc.).  Otherwise, automatically remove  it from the chart.
The indicator named Dollar_Index.ex4 is located in the  ../MQL4 /indicators/MLWS folder
This is the MQL4 code I wrote to achieve this:
//--- install DXY indicator for USD pairs -------------------------->
void CheckAndInstallDXY() {
   int subWindowIndex = 1; // We are checking Subwindow 1
   Print("Installing DXY in Subwindow 1...");
   double handle = iCustom(Symbol(), Period(), "MLWS\\Dollar_Index", 0, 0, subWindowIndex);
   WindowRedraw();    
   if (handle > 0) {
      Print("DXY indicator successfully installed.");       
      indiCount=1;          
   } else {
      Print("Failed to install DXY indicator.");      
      indiCount=0;   
   }      
}

When I execute the code and afterwards click on the Experts tab in MT4 terminal it shows the indicator has been successfully installed. (see image below)

However the indicator is not visible in the sub window for USD related pairs.
